# Python conditions with parenthesis in a while not loop

Tags: python, karel

So I'm learning programming with Karel and I'm a little confused about conditionals with parenthesis and specifically what would happen in a loop.

```
def build_line():
    while not (front_is_blocked() or beeper_is_present()):
        face_east()
        put_beeper()
        move()
```

```
def build_line():
    while not front_is_blocked() or not beeper_is_present():
        face_east()
        put_beeper()
        move()
```

In the line `while not (front_is_blocked() or beeper_is_present())` and `while not front_is_blocked() or not beeper_is_present()` do they mean the same thing? That the loop will only start if the front is clear OR there are no beepers present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The expression `not (front_is_blocked() or beeper_is_present())` is equivalent to `not front_is_blocked() and not beeper_is_present()` per [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).  Notice the `and` vs `or` in your 2nd code sample.

Comment: how about `while not (front_is_blocked() and beeper_is_present())`? would it become `not front_is_blocked() and not beeper_is_present()`?

Comment: No.  `not (front_is_blocked() and beeper_is_present())` is equivalent to `not front_is_blocked() or not beeper_is_preesent()`

Comment: oh so the not operator not only inverses the function values but also the connective?

Comment: Yes.  Check out the link to DeMorgan's Laws.  I use it often to simplify expressions.  Make sure you accept the best answer so we know you are all set.

Comment: is safe to assume that `while not (front_is_blocked() and beeper_is_present())` is therefore the same as `while not front_is_blocked() or not beeper_is_present()` then?

Comment: Yes, they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

They aren't the same.  Here's a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) where each column represents a different combination of `front_blocked` and `beeper_present` values:

```
T T F F  front_blocked
T F T F  beeper_present
-----------------------
T T T F  front_blocked or beeper_present
F F F T  not (front_blocked or beeper_present)
F T T T  not front_blocked or not beeper_present
```

Note that `front_blocked or beeper_present` is a simple `or`, which means it's true as long as there's at least one `T` value (i.e. in all scenarios *except* `F F`), and the following line `not (front_blocked or beeper_present)` is the inverse of that, making it true *only* for `F F` (this is a [logical NOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_NOR)).

`not front_blocked or not beeper_present` inverts the individual values before taking the `or`, so it's true as long as there's at least one `F` value, making it true in all scenarios *except* `T T` (this is a [logical NAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_NAND) -- you could also write it as `not (front_blocked and beeper_present)`).

Answer (score 0):

Both the functions are not same. In first function , while loop will only execute when both other functions (ie front_is_blocked and beeper_is_present) returning False, while in later function even if either of function is returning True, while statement will execute.